# Compiling my own mktexfmt

Tags: pdftex, compiling, format-files, javascript

I'm trying to compile my own version of pdftex which works fine.
However, I must compile my own format file (fmt) for that.
This should be done with `mktexfmt`. My problem is that I don't know where to find the souce code for `mktexfmt` (for Linux).

Can anybody give me a hint where to find it?

---

OK, looks like I need a small crash course in the LaTeX architecture.

This is what I understand now:

1. I don't need `mktexfmt` to create a format, I can use `pdftex -ini -etex`
2. A format is necessary to teach `pdftex` to understand latex
3. When I have "teached" `pdftex` how to understand latex I can parse latex files with `pdftex` and create pdf files from this

Is this correct?

If so, where do I get a .tex file to create a format? [This ctan package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latex) looks good, but I cannot download it.

Sorry for beeing so dumb, but until now I only created nice pdfs with latex but I never got that deep into its architecture.

EDIT: I don't see the relevance of *why* I want to do this. But OK it's because I want to port PDFTeX to Javascript using `emscripten`. Does this help?

Comment: If you are compiling your own pdfTeX, then I'd imagine you are better off with the traditional approach of `pdftex --ini <file>`, maybe with `*` before the file name if you want the e-TeX extensions enabled. (You don't say which format you are after.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: I'm still not clear _why_ you need to create your own format files, or to compile pdfTeX, both of which are pretty unusual tasks.

Comment: About the addition: you need quite a big part of a TeX distribution, if you want to use (La)TeX for serious work. So compiling it without the `kpathsea` library and without an accompanying TeX distribution does not make much sense.

Comment: Now I use this: [Making TeX work, Chapter 4. Macro Packages](http://makingtexwork.sourceforge.net/mtw/ch04.html).

Comment: Have the sources of mktexfmt become available since this question was asked?

I would also be interested in studying them, as this has become a recent development topic for LaTeXML.

Answer (score 7):

If the TeX code for the format is `myformat.tex`, then

```
pdftex -ini -etex -output-format=pdf myformat
```

will produce the file `myformat.fmt` that you can place anywhere the TeX programs would search for formats; for instance in

```
~/texmf/web2c/pdftex/
```

The options:

- `-ini` means "be INITEX" (mandatory for building a format)
- `-etex` means "enable the e-TeX extensions (recommended)
- `-output-format=pdf` means "output will be PDF"

Comment: I would also recommend you to use the -enc (encTeX extension) argument, which allows you to enter your whole text as UTF-8 (with some configuration beforehand)

Comment: What is myformat.tex and what is it supposed to contain? Is the source file for `pdftex.fmt` included in e.g. the texlive source tree?