# TeX format does not work in pdftex

Tags: pdftex, tex-core, format-files

I have format Finnish.fmt it works on TeX like:

```
tex --fmt=Finnish letter.tex
```

On pdftex i get:

```
pdftex --fmt=Finnish letter.tex

error:
---! Finnish.fmt was written by tex
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)
```

what can be the challenge? can this be remedied.

I am running linux on 64 bit debian

Comment: you must have made Finish.fmt with something like `tex --ini Finish` you need to make a pdffinish.fmt with something like `pdftex --ini --jobname=pdffinish Finish` then specify `pdffinish` as your format

Comment: I've never heard of a `Finnish.fmt`. [What's the problem you are trying to solve?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2450/5763)

Comment: Finnish.fmt is a format I made with finnish hyphenation and the characters of öä and ÖÄ from finnish linux and windows keyboard.

Comment: @HannuRouhiainen: So what's the problem you are trying to solve and why do you need a special format for that (and can not use e.g. LuaLaTeX)? Note that special formats might make your documents unportable.

Comment: David, could you make your comment into an answer as suggested by samcarter.

Answer (score 2):

Format files are binary memory dumps that are closely tied to the [engine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21863/5763) they have been created with, so you would need a format file created by pdftex. But I strongly suggest that you don't import some binary blob from somewhere on the internet but instead [create it yourself](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89723/5763).

Comment: This format is made by me, it is not downloaded.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83486/36296 for explanation about precompiling

Answer (score 2):

pdftex format needs to be done with pdftex, like David Carlisle suggested in his comment:

> you need to make a pdffinish.fmt with something like `pdftex --ini --jobname=pdffinish Finish` then specify pdffinish as your format

This resolved my problem.

Comment: Ok, I did not know.